# How to make space between li tags without using margin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

I'm studying SCSS and I want to use `justify-content: space-between` or make space between `li` without using margin, but it doesn't work and nothing changed on browser. Did I miss something? or Did I do some stupid thing?

React component

```
function Nav() {
  return (
    <div className="nav">
      <div className="nav-title">PROJECT</div>
      <ul className="nav-ul">
        <li className="nav-list">HOME</li>
        <li className="nav-list">USER</li>
        <li className="nav-list">INFO</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

scss

```
$nav-size: 60px;

.nav {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: $nav-size;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;

  .nav-title {
    font-size: calc(#{$nav-size} * 0.5);
  }

  .nav-ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
}
```

It works in `.nav` but it dosen't work in `.nav-ul` class

Comment: First of all, none of your HTML elements in the code you have shown actually has any class. `className` is JavaScript syntax, the HTML attribute to assign class names to an HTML element is simply called `class`.

Comment: You'll get more help if you make it as easy as possible for people to reproduce your problem. Provide CSS not SCSS. Provide HTML not JSX. Use the live demo feature of the question editor.

Comment: add width: 100% to .nav-ul class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Use It.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
display: grid;
grid-auto-flow: column;
grid-column-gap: 1px;
}
ul#menu li {
  display:inline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Horizontal List</h2>

<ul id="menu">
  <li>HTML</li>
  <li>CSS</li>
  <li>JavaScript</li>
  <li>PHP</li>
</ul>  

</body>
</html>
```

But I recommend to use padding or margin.